# Python Turtle graphics scale size and position

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want some help on Python turtle graphics. I need to create a house which goes each time smaller in a `for ... in range()` loop.

I am creating scenery with three houses composed of basic turtle shapes. Is there a way, when I create a house with basic shapes, I can use a `for ... in range()` loop  to change the house position and make it a little smaller in size?

What I am trying so far:

```
def house(turtlename,hs,xroof,xdoor,xwindow,ywindow):
 housesquare(turtlename,hs)
 turtlename.pu()
 turtlename.goto ((int(hs*xroof),int(hs*1)))
 turtlename.pd()
 housetriangle(turtlename,hs)
 turtlename.pu()
 turtlename.goto((int(hs*xdoor),0 ))
 turtlename.pd()
 housedoor(turtlename,hs*0.7,hs*0.3)
 turtlename.pu()
 turtlename.goto((int(hs*xwindow), int(hs*ywindow)))
 turtlename.pd()
 housesquare(turtlename,hs*0.3)
```

Using this code, I try to draw a second house with smaller size. The `goto()` command disturbs the whole shape and I have to do it everything manually but the task is to use `for ... in range(4)` to draw four houses, each to be smaller and placed at a little distance.

Comment: If you guys just help me to create a house witch goes each time smaller in loop. It will be a great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw in a ***relative***, not ***absolute***, fashion.  You can do this with `.goto()` and it tends to look something like:

```
turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + hs * xwindow, turtle.ycor() + hs * ywindow)
```

That is, move relative to where you are now.  However, it may be simpler to avoid `.goto()` altogether and work with relative motion methods like `.forward()`, `.backward()`, `.left()`, & `.right()`.  Here's a rework of your code using those relative motion methods:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def housesquare(turtle, width):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)

def housetriangle(turtle, base):
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(base)
        turtle.left(120)

def housedoor(turtle, height, width):
    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)

def house(turtle, hs, xroof, xdoor, xwindow, ywindow):
    housesquare(turtle, hs)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(hs)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(hs * xroof)
    turtle.pendown()
    housetriangle(turtle, hs)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(hs)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(hs * xdoor)
    turtle.pendown()
    housedoor(turtle, hs * 0.7, hs * 0.3)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.backward(hs * xdoor)
    turtle.forward(hs * xwindow)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(hs * ywindow)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    housesquare(turtle, hs * 0.3)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.backward(hs * xwindow)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.backward(hs * ywindow)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle()

size = 100

for factor in range(1, 4):

    house(yertle, size / factor, 0.0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4)

    yertle.penup()
    yertle.forward(1.5 * size / factor)
    yertle.right(15)
    yertle.pendown()

yertle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Notice that it can not only draw the house at different sizes, but rotate it as well, due to the relative drawing logic:

[image]